# callback in nested state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am fairly new to JS and I am having a bit trouble in understanding how to properly implement the callback passed to setState in React, for a controlled input. The following code is what I have so far:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    ...
        this.state = {
            properties: {
                width: '',
                height: ''
            }
         this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this); //edit 1
    }

   handleChange(e){
     this.setState(() => ({ properties[e.target.name]: e.target.value })) //edit 2  
   }

   render(){
       return(
         <input
           type="text"
           value={this.state.properties.width}
           name="width"
           onChange={this.handleChange} />
        ...
       )
   }      
}
```

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYQgNv?editors=0010

Comment: that wont fix the issue.

Comment: Seems like you missed to `bind` a `handleChange` method in a constructor function `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)`

Comment: Indeed I forgot it but it does not solve the issue as @Iluisrojass stated already.

Comment: @Li357, it is not duplicate of the question you linked. This question has to do with `react` `SyntheticEvent` and the fact that they are being reused and nullified after the event callback has been invoked, which causes problems with `setState` which is async.

Comment: @margaretkru That's true, I'll lift the duplicate status though the linked question explains part of the problem.

Comment: yes, I was pretty sure myself that proper handling of `this` context in the event handler would fix the problem.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to take the values off of the event before calling setState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `handleChange` declaration:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    ...
   handleChange = (e) => {
     this.setState({ properties[e.target.name]: e.target.value })  
   }
    ...
}
```

When you write `handleChange = (e) => {...}` <del>it will bind `this` pointer of the function to your component so that you will be able to access `setState`</del> as pointed out by @Li357, it doesn't not bind at all, on the contrary it creates a property of the class that is an arrow function that doesn't bind `this`, capturing the `this` value of the surrounding scope, the class.

---

Update:

It has been pointed out that using arrow functions as class properties is an experimental feature, so it is safer to use `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` in `constructor` of the component. 
I got the example working with this code:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        properties: {...prevState.properties, ...{ [target.name]: target.value } }
    })
  );
}
```

I am not entirely sure why it behaves the way it does, I am guessing it has to do with the fact that `setState` is async and `react` wraps events in its own `SyntheticEvent` which `will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked` (see [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)). So if you store the original reference to `target` outside of `setState` it will get scoped and used inside `setState`.

Here is a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pykz0zwkpx).

---

Update 2:

According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling), one can't access react `SyntheticEvent` in an asynchronous way. One way of dealing with this would to be call `event.persist()` which will remove the wrapper, but this might not be a good idea since `SyntheticEvent` is a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event which makes sure the events work identically across all browsers.

Comment: i might be wrong, but i believe this functionality requires a transpiler plugin, as it is not standard in es2015.

Comment: @lluisrojass, yes, you are right, it is not part of es6. I wasn't aware of that since I usually use `stage-2` babel preset which includes this functionality. thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @margaretkru I have updated the pen but the binding doesn't seem to make it work.

Comment: @Li357, could you please point out some source explaining how arrow functions work under the hood when they are used as class properties? I can't seem to find any well-written explanation of what happens with `this` pointer.

Comment: @margaretkru You can test it out with [the Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oCMwCdoF5oAKASgID4VoB6a3HeAd2gDMBXAO2ABcBLeDtAAODIQFMc3AJ7QA5vDExeHbkm4ALMdGACI3HGx7wcAGmiNNOLQAMNvCNeHxl3GKugatoSBHQZofgC-fn7YOKRUtFaybOB4ALZiGvAAJn4YQaiBQA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0). Arrow functions don't bind `this`.