# TypeError: evt.target is null in functional setState

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

What's the major difference bewteen these two functions?

```
handleOnChange(evt) {
    this.setState(() => ({
        tickerName: evt.target.value
    }));
}

handleOnChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ tickerName: evt.target.value });
}
```

And why with the handleOnChange() function that change the state directly this works fine?

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.tickerName}
    onChange={(evt) => this.handleOnChange(evt)} 
/>
```

When I use the first function that change the state with a callback I get this error:

```
TypeError: evt.target is null
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090588/4467208

Comment: for more details about setState check the [**DOC**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), updater function is required when next state value is dependent on previous state value, and in your case it's not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are two different syntaxes for setState

First:

```
handleOnChange(evt) {
    this.setState(() => ({
        tickerName: evt.target.value
    }));
}
```

uses the updater function as the first argument.

Second:

```
handleOnChange(evt) {
   this.setState({ tickerName: evt.target.value });
}
```

uses the object to be updated

When using the synthetic event in the updater function you need to use `event.persist()`

From the **[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)**:

> the SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent object
>   will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event
>   callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such,
>   you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

Your fist case would look like

```
handleOnChange(evt) {
    evt.persist();
    this.setState(() => ({
        tickerName: evt.target.value
    }));
}
```

Or instead of using `event.persist()` you could store the event in another object

```
handleOnChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({
        tickerName: evt.target.value
    }));
}
```

**P.S.** You should use the updater function for setState only when you wish to update the current state based on `prevState` or `props`

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxllr08m85)**

Comment: So in my case is it quite useless to update the state with a callback? Because I read that the new standard way for update the state is with a callback, isn't it?.

Comment: The updater function in `setState` has format `(prevState, props) => stateChange`, so if you don't need access to the previous state I would say go with the second one that just takes an update object. [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) has very good explanation on methods of calling `setState`.

Comment: @margaretkru, yes thats the most basic thing we should care about.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri, do you know if there is any detailed and documented explanation to why there is no need to call `event.persit()` or cache values from the event when calling `setState` with an object, but there is a need to do so when using updater function? Shouldn't `setState` work async in both cases? Even react docs on [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) don't use of `event.persist()` .

Comment: @margaretkru, so when you simply write `this.setState({ tickerName: evt.target.value });` , you are simply passing an object to setState, and the . value to tickerName key is assigned immedialtely, however in the updater function its nothing but a callback invoked with the necessary parameters by setState and by that time the event properties are nullified. Hope I could make it clear

Comment: wow, how could I have not realized that ... brain fart) @Shubham Khatri, thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

`React` wraps events in its own `SyntheticEvent` which `will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked` (see [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)).

According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling), one can't access react `SyntheticEvent` in an asynchronous way and `setState` is async. So when `setState` is executed your `evt` might be null because it gets reused by `react`. Since the first function uses a callback with access to previous state in `setState`, by the time the callback is executed the event `evt` is reused and nullified by `react`. In the second case the update object with the event value is created right away and passed in directly and it doesn't create a similar problem.

If you need to use `setState` with a callback you need to take care of the event possibly being null when the callback is executed. One way of dealing with this would be store the original reference to `target` outside of `setState` it will get scoped and used inside `setState`. Like this:

```
handleOnChange(evt) {
    const target = evt.target;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        tickerName: target.value
    }));
}
```

I wrote a more detailed answer to why `react` events get null in `setState` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068660/6053299).