# Error: If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to access screenX for onMouseOver event.

This is the current code:

```
<h1 ref={textInput => { this.state.textInput = textInput; }} 
    onMouseMove={this.increaseValue}>Some text here</h1>
```

Increase value is defined like sp:

```
increaseValue = (e) => {
    console.log(e.screenX,);
}
```

However I get this error and not sure what it means:

*This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `screenX` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling for more information.*

Comment: There is a link attached there which explains what it is.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075356/why-setstate-with-callback-does-not-work-properly/48075517#48075517 for a use case scenario

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thanks, it was exactly the explanation I wanted.

Comment: @CoderBC, Glad to have helped. I am closing this question as a duplicate then