# react resuable component issue when use multiple time in same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, reusability

I'm making an input component and i want to use it whereever i want.

> input component code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            [props.name] : props.value
        };

        this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this)
    }

    handleUserInput(e){
        console.log(e.target.name);
        this.setState( prevState => ({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const {
            type,
            value,
            placeholder,
            className,
            name,
            id,
            form_control,
            disabled,
            readOnly,
            minLength,
            maxLength,
            ref,
            autoFocus,
            message
        } = this.props;

        let CLASS =
            (form_control ? "form-control" : "") + " " + (className || "");

        if ( message ){
            CLASS += (className ? ' ' : '') + 'is-invalid ';
        }

        return (
            <input
                type={type}
                name={name}
                value={this.state[name]}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                className={CLASS}
                id={id}
                disabled={disabled}
                readOnly={readOnly}
                minLength={minLength}
                maxLength={maxLength}
                ref={ref}
                autoFocus={autoFocus}
                onChange={this.handleUserInput}
            />
        );
    }
}

Input.defaultProps = {
    type: "text",
    form_control: true,
    value : ""
};

Input.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    id: PropTypes.string,
    form_control: PropTypes.bool,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    readOnly: PropTypes.bool,
    minLength: PropTypes.number,
    maxLength: PropTypes.number,
    ref: PropTypes.string,
    autoFocus: PropTypes.bool
};

export default Input;
```

> confirmable component code :

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Input from "./input";
import FeedBack from "../static/feedback";

class ConfirmAble extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { message } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <Input {...this.props} />
                <FeedBack text={message} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ConfirmAble.propTypes = {
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default ConfirmAble;
```

> I'm using this confirmable component many times in same component like below :

```
<ConfirmAble
type="email"
name="email"
value={this.state.email}
message={this.state.formErrors.email}
/>

<ConfirmAble
type="password"
name="password"
value={this.state.password}
message={this.state.formErrors.password}
/>
```

but input valuee can not change. if i added handleUserInput function to component i got this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null at t. (input.jsx:19)

line 19 is

> [ e.target.name ] : e.target.value ( in the handleUserInput function )

If I remove one of component, it works.

Why does not work? Where is the problem ?

Comment: Check the duplicate, the error will come in `handleUserInput` function

Comment: where is the duplication code ? i checked out but found nothing

Comment: you need to check the Duplicate question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075356/why-setstate-with-callback-does-not-work-properly, Check the answer and it will answer your question too

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thank you su much ...

i changed the handleUserInput like below as it say the duplicate question: 

handleUserInput(e) {
  var _name = e.target.name,
   _value = e.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
   [_name]: _value
  }));
 }

it works :)

Comment: Great it worked out for you

Comment: Consider upvoting the duplicate question and answer so that it gains more visibility