# How can I call e.preventDefault() inside an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

When the user clicks the submit button of my form, `handleSubmit` is called. So, I want to properly call the e.preventDefault() inside my ajax call which is not possible due to the async nature of ajax. How can I fix this?

```
class FormRegister extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            email: '',
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        // some code here

        // Check for username or email already exists
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/checkEmailUsername',
            data: {
                username: this.state.username,
                email: this.state.email
            }
        }).then(function(incomingJSON) {
            console.log('incomingJSON:', incomingJSON);
            if (incomingJSON.error) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can you `apply` and `call`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075356/typeerror-evt-target-is-null-in-functional-setstate/48075517#48075517

Comment: You're thinking about this in the wrong way. AJAX is async so you can't just call `e.preventDefault` anywhere; you need to call it before the AJAX code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using is asynchronous. This means that you need to slightly change how you are handling things. Move the `e.preventDefault()` call before your asynchronous code, like this.

This code assumes you have a `form` element with a ref name of `form`.

```
class FormRegister extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      email: '',
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/checkEmailUsername',
      data: {
        username: this.state.username,
        email: this.state.email
      }
    }).then(function(incomingJSON) {
      console.log('incomingJSON:', incomingJSON);
      if (incomingJSON.error) {
        // Handle errors here.
        return;
      }

      // Submit the form.
      this.refs.form.submit();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: "// Handle everything else here." — Everything else is **not** preventing the default action in the first place.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default action.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem. You are **always** preventing the default action, but the question wants it prevented **conditionally**

Comment: It's not possible to do it the way he is asking. This is why I mention for him to slightly change the way he is handling things.

Comment: But your slight change just means the code doesn't work in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, at least not to any effect.

When the event listener finishes running, the default behaviour of the event triggers. **Later** the HTTP response comes back and the promise is resolved. At this point is to **too late** to call `preventDefault()` with any effect.

You need to take a different approach.

Possible approaches include:

- Do your Ajax dependant validation as soon as the input is filled in, and set a flag if it fails. Use that to `preventDefault` in the submit event handler. (This risks timing issues so you will fall over to server side input checking more often).
- *Always* `preventDefault()` and then conditionally submit the form programmatically.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(document).ready(() => {
  $("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {

    //prevent Default

    event.preventDefault();


    // Send form
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
```

I hope this can help you

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/8631884

Comment: I don't get your Point? What is the Problem with that?

Comment: Well, that's some code that completely lacks anything resembling an explanation of how it solves the problem (which it doesn't, since the goal is to *conditionally* `preventDefault` depending on the Ajax response).

Comment: @felix9607 jQuery and React are both UI Libraries, so if you are already using React, then why include jQuery? I don't think there's any use of updating the DOM with jQuery when React can do that for you very efficiently.. Hope you get the point :)