# What's the difference between using a function to return an object in setState and using an object directly?

Tags: reactjs

In the following, the handleChange method throws an error when, inside setState, I use a function to return an object, but works fine when I update inputvalue directly as an object

```
   class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          inputvalue: ''
      }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(() => {
      return {inputvalue: event.target.elements.name.value}//throws an error but works fine if I use just use object with out using a functon to return
    }       
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleChange}>
              <label>Name  </label>
              <input type="text" name="option"  />
              <button>submit</button>
          </form>
         <p> {this.state.inputvalue}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Warning that happens:

*Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If     you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `stopPropagation` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html for more information.*

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: I don't see any error text in your post, please edit it in. And on a more practical note, why would you return anything at all? `setState` completely ignores function returns from a post-state-update callback. If you need access to the value you're returning, that is _literally_ what component state is already for: don't return it after updating the state, _update the state with that value_ to begin with =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this:

> the SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

You should call persist method when using a function as updater.

```
handleChange (event) {
    event.persist();

    this.setState(() => {
        ...
    }
}
```

Take a look at this answer:

[TypeError: evt.target is null in functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075356/typeerror-evt-target-is-null-in-functional-setstate)

Comment: super helpful, the persist method made the error go away. I also had to use preventDefault from my code editor refreshing immediately. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

i think u are accessing here wrong:

```
event.target.elements.name.value
```

should be

```
event.target.elements.option.value // because u set the name attribute to option (name="option") on the input element
```

and if i don't mistake the error is that u trying to access null reference right?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo, should be option. Doesn't solve the original problem but definitely doesn't help that i made that typo :)